# impdp expects wrong file path

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe, datapump

**Summary:**

I'm using expdp / impdp to export a database from a test / demo database (Oracle 11.2) and import it into an instance of Oracle Express (11g) on my own machine.

The import fails because it tries to create imported database files in *locations from the source server*.  Literally, my source temo / test database is on a machine with an E:\ drive.  But my computer only has one C:\ drive.  And I get errors because it can't find things on the E:\ drive.

This error feels like a red herring.  Either I've missused my tools, or I'm getting a slightly bogus error message.

**Questions:**

- Did I run expdp wrong, and include full file paths somehow
- Is my real problem that the SIDs don't line up ('demo' vs 'XE')
- If I need to remap something, what specifically woudl that be?

Many thanks.

**Full explanition**

I run this command on the demo server:

```
expdp name/password@localhost:1521/demo full=y directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=demo.dmp logfile=exportDemo.log
```

I've coppied the file to my notebook, to the appropriate folder within Oracle (C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\admin\XE\dpdump).  I then run this command:

```
impdp SYSTEM/password@localhost:1521/XE  directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=demo.dmp logfile=impdpDemo.log full=y
```

The command runs for a while, but with errors:

```
;;; 
Import: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Sat Jun 11 10:32:21 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

    ;;; 
    Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
    Master table "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
    Starting "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01":  SYSTEM/********@localhost:1521/XE directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=demo.dmp logfile=impdpDemo.log full=y 
    Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/TABLESPACE
    ORA-31684: Object type TABLESPACE:"UNDOTBS1" already exists
    ORA-31684: Object type TABLESPACE:"TEMP" already exists
    ORA-31684: Object type TABLESPACE:"USERS" already exists
    ORA-39083: Object type TABLESPACE failed to create with error:
    ORA-01119: error in creating database file 'E:\ORACLE\PRODUCT\11.2.0\ORADATA\DEMO\MOBILE01.DBF'
    ORA-27040: file create error, unable to create file
    OSD-04002: unable to open file
    O/S-Error: (OS 3) The system cannot find the path specified.
```

This is the start of the log, but variations of this error happen throughout the import process, and it ultimately fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. path to data files is included in full dump.
2. No, SIDs don't have to match
3. You may want to add `REMAP_DATAFILE` option (https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-7C9DDBED-91AC-4FA2-AB91-1FF214DA89B0.htm#SUTIL926 ) to impdp .  Alternatively, you can just pre-create all tablespaces on target database.